# Pytest always runs into pdb trace and gets stuck

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I'm building a testing suite using pytest and there's a weird bug that's popping up.
My test scripts execute fine when I run them as python scripts but on executing them with pytest, it runs into pdb shell and I have to type `continue` to proceed. The script doesn't make any calls to pdb or any debugger.
Here's a simple script

```
# test_main.py
from yolov5 import train

def test_main():
    train_params = train(cfg="yolov5s.yaml", epochs=1, project="test_run")

#if __name__ == "__main__":
#    test_main()
```

This script runs fine when called using `python test_main.py` but here's what happens when running `python -m pytest`:

```
rootdir: ..., configfile: pytest.ini, testpaths: tests/
plugins: sphinx-0.4.0, cov-3.0.0
collected 1 item                                                                                                                        

tests/test_main.py::test_main 
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> PDB runcall (IO-capturing turned off) >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
> /Users/ayush/yolov5/tests/test_main.py(5)test_main()
-> train_params = train(cfg="yolov5s.yaml", epochs=1, project="test_run")
(Pdb) continue

>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> PDB continue (IO-capturing resumed) >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

```
# pytest.ini

[pytest]
testpaths = tests/
python_classes = Test* *Test
log_format = %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(message)s
log_level = DEBUG
markers =
filterwarnings =
```

I need to manually continue the script. I don't understand why this happens as I've not imported pdb in my test script. I've searched for this issue but couldn't find any answers. What could be causing this and how can this be fixed?

Comment: what's in your pytest.ini..?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your code. Is this supposed to be the test code? If yes, why are you running the test function manually - what should that do? If not, you shouldn't name the function `test_xxx`.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I'm running it manually just to check if its executing fine. The issue is mainly with pytest execution

Comment: @thebjorn sorry, just added that in the question description.

Comment: Do you have any PYTEST_xx environment variables?  (the behavior is triggered by the `--pdb` flag to pytest).

Comment: @thebjorn No there's no PYTEST_xx like env variable. I also haven't added any manually.

Comment: Any other config files (setup.cfg, tox.ini, pyproject.toml) that could have set the option? If not I'm rapidly running out of ideas... (there was a pytest.set_trace() function when pytest had problems with pdb.set_trace() but seems very unlikely...)

Comment: @thebjorn okay I found the problem. It was --trace flag. It's supposed to run into pdb if a test errors out but it was running into that even on warnings. Removing that fixed the problem

Comment: @AyushChaurasia I think that then you should answer your own question